# Pandas groupby issue after melt bug?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-melt

Python version 3.8.12
Pandas 1.4.1

Given the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1000] * 4,
    'date': ['2022-01-01'] * 4,
    'ts': pd.date_range('2022-01-01', freq='5M', periods=4),
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 6, size=4),
    'B': np.random.rand(4)
})
```

That looks like this:

|  | id | date | ts | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 0.98019 |
| 1 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:05:00 | 3 | 0.82021 |
| 2 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00 | 4 | 0.549684 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:15:00 | 5 | 0.0818311 |

I transposed the columns `A` and `B` with pandas `melt`:

```py
melted = df.melt(
    id_vars=['id', 'date', 'ts'],
    value_vars=['A', 'B'],
    var_name='label',
    value_name='value',
    ignore_index=True
)
```

That looks like this:

|  | id | date | ts | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | A | 4 |
| 1 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:05:00 | A | 3 |
| 2 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00 | A | 4 |
| 3 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:15:00 | A | 5 |
| 4 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | B | 0.98019 |
| 5 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:05:00 | B | 0.82021 |
| 6 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00 | B | 0.549684 |
| 7 | 1000 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 00:15:00 | B | 0.0818311 |

Then I `groupby` and select the first group:

```py
melted.groupby(['id', 'date']).first()
```

That gives me this:

```
                        ts label  value
id   date                              
1000 2022-01-01 2022-01-01     A    4.0
```

But I would expect this output instead:

```
                                 ts  A         B
id   date                                       
1000 2022-01-01 2022-01-01 00:00:00  4  0.980190
     2022-01-01 2022-01-01 00:05:00  3  0.820210
     2022-01-01 2022-01-01 00:10:00  4  0.549684
     2022-01-01 2022-01-01 00:15:00  5  0.081831
```

What am I not getting? Or this is a bug? Also why the `ts` columns is converted to a date?

Comment: So need `melted.groupby(['id', 'ts']).first()` ?

Comment: `Also why the ts columns is converted to a date?` - because time is `00:00:00` is not displayed `2022-01-01 00:00:00`, not converted to `date`

Answer (score 1):

I thought `first` will get the first group but instead it will get the first element for each group, as stated in the documentation for the aggregation functions of pandas.

To select the first group, I needed to use `get_group` function.